# Material-UI set <Select> to be as wide as widest <MenuItem>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to set a Mui Select field to be as wide as it's largest MenuItem. I have tried using the `autoWidth` prop on Select, but this doesn't seem to change anything. Here is a code sandbox showing the issue (I have also included a TextField implementation which has the same issue for me);

https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-select-width-issue-xmsp5?file=/src/App.js

When selecting between the 2 items the width of the select box will change. How do I programmatically fix it to be the width of the biggest MenuItem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The code below uses the following approach:

- Use the [keepMounted](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/modal/#Modal-prop-keepMounted) prop via `MenuProps` so that the menu is rendered even when it is not being displayed. Without this there isn't any easy way to determine its width (which is generally the width of the widest item so long as that fits fine).
- Pass a callback to the `ref` prop of the menu's `Paper` element. This allows the code to be notified once that paper element has been rendered to the DOM.
- Set the width of that paper element into state to use as the min width for the `Select`

```
import * as React from "react";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import Select, { SelectChangeEvent } from "@mui/material/Select";

export default function SelectAutoWidth() {
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };
  const [minWidth, setMinWidth] = React.useState<number | null>(null);
  const menuCallbackRef = React.useCallback(
    (menuDiv: HTMLDivElement | null) => {
      if (menuDiv !== null) {
        if (minWidth === null || minWidth !== menuDiv.clientWidth) {
          setMinWidth(menuDiv.clientWidth);
        }
      }
    },
    []
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1 }}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-autowidth-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-autowidth-label"
          id="demo-simple-select-autowidth"
          value={age}
          sx={minWidth === null ? {} : { minWidth: minWidth + 14 }}
          MenuProps={{
            keepMounted: true,
            slotProps: { paper: { ref: menuCallbackRef } },
          }}
          onChange={handleChange}
          label="Age"
        >
          <MenuItem value="">
            <em>None</em>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={10}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={21}>Twenty one</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={22}>Twenty one and a half</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/select-width-based-on-options-73dj92?file=%2Fsrc%2FDemo.tsx%3A10%2C55

Alternatively, you can use `TextField` with the `select` prop which then takes care of rendering the `FormControl` and `InputLabel` elements. Below is the equivalent code using `TextField` instead of `Select`:

```
import * as React from "react";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import { SelectChangeEvent } from "@mui/material/Select";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

export default function SelectAutoWidth() {
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = (
    event: SelectChangeEvent<unknown>,
    child: React.ReactNode
  ) => {
    setAge(event.target.value as string);
  };
  const [minWidth, setMinWidth] = React.useState<number | null>(null);
  const menuCallbackRef = React.useCallback(
    (menuDiv: HTMLDivElement | null) => {
      if (menuDiv !== null) {
        if (minWidth === null || minWidth !== menuDiv.clientWidth) {
          setMinWidth(menuDiv.clientWidth);
        }
      }
    },
    []
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <TextField
        select
        sx={{ m: 1 }}
        label="Age"
        SelectProps={{
          onChange: handleChange,
          sx: minWidth === null ? {} : { minWidth: minWidth + 14 },
          MenuProps: {
            keepMounted: true,
            slotProps: { paper: { ref: menuCallbackRef } },
          },
        }}
      >
        <MenuItem value="">
          <em>None</em>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={10}>Twenty</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={21}>Twenty one</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={22}>Twenty one and a half</MenuItem>
      </TextField>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/select-width-based-on-options-using-textfield-dqkk64?file=%2Fsrc%2FDemo.tsx%3A6%2C44

Comment: This is great, but it fails to mention the option of using a `<Textfield select>` instead of a `<Select>` component (which would let you eliminate the need for much of your answer).  Could you please include a mention of that option, and I'll happily award the bounty?

Comment: @machineghost I've added a `TextField` example, though that doesn't change things much.

Comment: Thanks.  I personally had no idea that a ton of things (like automatic width based on option width) just came "for free" when you use the `TextField select` instead of a `Select` ... so hopefully when others also have no idea, this answer will point them in the right direction.

Comment: @machineghost Automatic width based on option width doesn't come "for free" when using `TextField select`. The default behavior (which is to set the min width based on the selected option -- not the longest available option) isn't any different between the two approaches. `TextField` just simplifies specifying the label.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `fullWidth` property in the textfield component? try to specify a container of your desired width and the input will take up the full width of its container. ***or*** you can override the width of the texfield using in-text styling. as in the following:

```
<TextField select style = {{width: 200}}>
        <MenuItem key="1" value="1">
          Small Choice
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem key="2" value="2">
          Biiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiig Choice
        </MenuItem>
</TextField>
```

this solution is not the best, because you have to specify statically the max-width of the text field according to your menu item.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately, these aren't exactly what I'm looking for. I don't want the selector to take up the full width of the container, or to have to be manually set at a certain amount of pixels. Thanks for the suggestions though

Comment: The really key part of this answer isn't the styling or `fullWidth` ... it's that it uses a `<Textfield select ...>` instead of a `<Select`.  Just this change alone (possibly with a little CSS added) should solve OP's issue.